# any way to avoid referenced .dbproj from being "built" / deployed EVERY time

Tags: performance, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-data-tools

#### some background

take a solution setup like this:

```
dbproj-A

dbproj-B
  - references
    -dbproj-A
```

Whenever I set the startup-project to `dbproj-B` and F5-deploy, it *always* first builds and deploys `dbproj-A`, even when dbproj-A has not changed at all.

#### my question

- Is there any way to avoid this "always-build-and-deploy-references" behavior (since it takes about 10 mins to deploy `dbproj-A` in my case)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to build-->configuration manager and untick the projects you don't want built.

If the project never changes you can move it out of the solution and just reference the dacpac in your current project

Comment: Wish there was a mechanism that could detect changes and skip build.  Doing it manually as suggested complicates things a bit for us since we share the same codebase across a number of developers and would need to commit settings (.SLN file changes).